# Anonymous access for anonymous items

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication

I'm maintaining a SharePoint site, this site has anonymous access enabled:

- When anonymous user accesses the site's main page it works fine.
- When anonymous user accesses "Announcements" list it works fine.
- When anonymous user accesses an item from my "Announcements" list it works fine.

But, if an anonymous user creates a new item, only logged in users will be able to see this new item.

Anonymous users will be asked to login in order to access these "Anonymous items"

Why is that? Is there a way to change that behavior?

Comment: Have you set the anonymous access permissions on that lists by breaking the inherit permissions?

Comment: Do you find any way to fix it? I almost have the same problem.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213461/problem-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your content approval/draft security settings? Have you verified that the new items are indeed version 1.0?